# Google Sheets Importxml Xpath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to import both the link to the Google Maps image and the address of the council from [https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Albany+City+council+address&time=445678](https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Albany%20City%20council%20address&time=445678)

I have tried all sorts of Xpath expressions and keep getting a result saying the imported results were empty.

For the address I have tried:

```
//*[@class='_uX kno-fb-ctx']
//div[@class='_eF']
//*[@class='_eF']
//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ol/li/div/div/div/ol/li/div
```

The info I want appears in 3 places on that page - so any Xpath that gets it from one of these locations is what I am looking for:

```
<div class="_uX kno-fb-ctx" aria-level="3" role="heading" data-hveid="29" data-ved="0CB0QtwcoADAA"><div class="_eF">102 North Road, Yakamia WA 6330</div>

id="lnv_href"></a></div></td><td valign="top" style="color:#222;line-height:1.24">102 North Road, Yakamia WA 6330

<div class="_lR"><div class="_mr"><span style="font-weight:bold">Address:</span>&nbsp;<span>102 North Road, Yakamia WA 6330</span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The info I want appears in a few places on the page:

Comment: Sorry, I simply don't know what you're asking. Please edit your question to give more details about exactly what you're trying to achieve, and what you've done to do that

Comment: Hey Freefaller - hope the edited question makes more sense now.

Comment: You've put "google-spreadsheet" as a tag, but you don't show what you're doing in a spreadsheet. Are you using a built-in function? A custom function? Anything else that might help others reproduce the problem and possibly answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

1) info You want appears in 2 places on that page, probbably the best way is to use Xpath construction with `contains`.

2) for map use

```
//*[@id="media_result_group"]/ol/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/a/img/@src
or simple
//div[@class="rhsg4 rhsmap5col"]/a/img/@src
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can't do that because those data from Google result page can't be rendered easily by xpath into google spreadsheet. The reason is they are rendered by javascript (more tech savvy guys will correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked correct is incorrect. The content I was looking for is HTML and is able to be captured with ImportHTMl("URL" "table",4) but I did need to add WA (stands for Western Australia) to the search string.